# How to get first and last values from list<string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to get only `first` and `last` values from `List<string>`.

```
List<String> _ids = ids.Split(',').ToList();
```

above code gives me all `,` separated values

```
(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,)
```

> I need to take and show only 1st and last values , how can i do this?

```
output  aaa,ddd
```

I tried with `first` and `last` but i want to eliminate `,` which is there at the end of the string :(

Comment: I guess you haven't try anything for this.

Comment: There should be NO comma at the end when you split on a comma. If you think there is, it must be because of some code that you are NOT showing us. Please post a compilable example which gives the extra comma at the end.

Comment: I agree with Matthew Watson, is there a space at the end of the input string.  How are you testing the string value.  Where does the output come from (are you doing a `string.Join`)?

Comment: `,` is coming at the end because when i send parameters i add `,` after each parameter so that at `.cs` file it is coming there :(

Comment: ashuthinks, why can't you just use `string.Join` which won't add the last `,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `List<string>` as an array like;

```
List<string> _ids = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };
var first = _ids[0]; //first element
var last = _ids[_ids.Count - 1]; //last element
```

With using LINQ, you can use [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) methods.

```
List<string> _ids = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };
var first = _ids.First();
var last = _ids.Last();
Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(last);
```

Output will be;

```
aaa
ddd
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/6YsRB1)</kbd>.

**NOTE**: As Alexander Simonov [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981352/how-to-get-first-and-last-values-from-liststring#comment28037364_18981380), if your `List<string>` is empty, `First()` and `Last()` will throw exception. Be aware of [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) or [`.LastOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) methods.

Comment: Curiously, is there a reason you use `_ids[_ids.Count - 1];` instead of `_ids.Last()`?

Comment: Actually, `.First()` and `.Last()` may throw an exception when `_ids` list is empty. So it's better to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and `.LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov or bounds check first.

Comment: exactly true but instead of linq can i do it in other way please as i want to eliminate , which is at end of the string ;(

Comment: My question is: Why did the OP say he was getting a "," at the end?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It wasn't there at the first revision of the question `:)`. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18981352/1

Comment: @SonerGönül Ah ok, that makes more sense. I think he's not telling us something important...

Answer (score 4):

The simply answer is using Linq

```
string[] idsTemp = ids.Split(',');
List<string> _ids = new List<string> { {idsTemp.First()}, {idsTemp.Last()}};
```

You may want a little more complexity because if the length is 0 an exception will be thrown and if the length is 1 then the same value gets returned twice.

```
public static class StringHelper {
  public List<string> GetFirstLast(this string ids) {
    string[] idsTemp = ids.Split(',');
    if (idsTemp.Length == 0) return new List<string>();
    return (idsTemp.Length > 2) ?
       new List<string> {{ idsTemp.First() }, { idsTemp.Last() }} :
       new List<string> {{ idsTemp.First() }};
  }
}
```

You can then use this extension methods.

```
List<string> firstLast = ids.GetFirstLast();
```

**EDIT - NON Linq Version**

```
public static class StringHelper {
  public List<string> GetFirstLast(this string ids) {
    string[] idsTemp = ids.Split(',');
    if (idsTemp.Length == 0) return new List<string>();
    return (idsTemp.Length > 2) ?
       new List<string> { {idsTemp[0] }, { idsTemp[idsTemp.Length-1] }} :
       new List<string> {{ idsTemp[0] }};
  }
}
```

**EDIT - REMOVE THE TRAILING `,`**

Using either of the preceeding methods, Linq or NonLinq you probably want to do.

```
List<string> firstLast = ids.Trim(new[]{','}).GetFirstLast();
```

Comment: I find using Linq a bit of overkill in this situation, but it is technically right, so +1.

Comment: exactly true but instead of linq can i do it in other way please as i want to eliminate `,` which is at end of the string ;(

Comment: @Renan It could be considered overkill but I find `idsTemp.Last()` far more expressive that `idsTemp[idsTemp.Length - 1]`. Linq does allow your code to be expressed as what you mean a lot easier.

Comment: @ashuthinks If you are trying to remove a trailing `,` have you just thought of using `Trim(new[] {','})`

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = _ids.First();
var last = _ids.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_ids.First()
_ids.Last()
```

Acording to "List-Class" Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/s6hkc2c4.aspx

Comment: That's not actual part of the Class, its a Linq extension and requires you to use the `System.Linq` namespace. Whilst the answer is not technically wrong it could lead to a little confusion!

Answer (score 0):

By hands:

```
string first = null;
string last = null;
if (_ids.Count > 0)
{
    first = _ids[0];
    last = _ids[_ids.Count - 1];
}
```

By LINQ:

```
string first = _ids.FirstOrDefault();
string last = _ids.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: exactly true but instead of linq can i do it in other way please as i want to eliminate , which is at end of the string ;(

Comment: @ashuthinks, the version called `By hands` is exactly without LINQ.

Comment: how can i elimate `,` which is at end of string :(

Comment: @ashuthinks, call `ids.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead of `ids.Split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the last comment from the OP:

*", is coming at the end because when i send parameters i add , after each parameter so that at .cs file it is coming there"*

It looks like you are trying to generate a string containing comma-separated values from an array of strings.

You can do this using [`string.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join.aspx), like so:

```
string[] test = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"};

string joined = string.Join(",", test);

Console.WriteLine(joined); // Prints "aaaa,bbbb,cccc"
```